# Conv2DCustomBackpropInput: Size of out_backprop doesn't match computed:

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, generator, tf.keras

The error is:
InvalidArgumentError:  Conv2DCustomBackpropInput: Size of out_backprop doesn't match computed: actual = 16, computed = 5 spatial_dim: 1 input: 10 filter: 2 output: 16 stride: 2 dilation: 1
[[node U-Net/conv2d_transpose_29/conv2d_transpose (defined at :1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_40216]

Function call stack:
train_function

Actualy , I'm working on a semantic segmentation project , I'm building a Unet model and when I get to the fitting part I got this issue . I saw  people talking about using padding='same' in the Conv2D transpose but still I have the same error . Please help me

This is the code :

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, concatenate, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, MaxPool2D, Concatenate


def conv_block(input, num_filters):
    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)   #Not in the original network. 
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)  #Not in the original network
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    return x

#Encoder block: Conv block followed by maxpooling


def encoder_block(input, num_filters):
    x = conv_block(input, num_filters)
    p = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(x)
    return x, p   

#Decoder block
#skip features gets input from encoder for concatenation

def decoder_block(input, skip_features, num_filters):
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_filters, (2, 2), strides=2, padding="same",dilation_rate=(1, 1))(input)
    x = Concatenate()([x, skip_features])
    x = conv_block(x, num_filters)

    return x

#Build Unet using the blocks
def build_unet(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    s1, p1 = encoder_block(inputs, 64)
    s2, p2 = encoder_block(p1, 128)
    s3, p3 = encoder_block(p2, 256)
    s4, p4 = encoder_block(p3, 512)

    b1 = conv_block(p4, 1024) #Bridge

    d1 = decoder_block(b1, s4, 512)
    d2 = decoder_block(d1, s3, 256)
    d3 = decoder_block(d2, s2, 128)
    d4 = decoder_block(d3, s1, 64)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, 1, padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(d4)  #Binary (can be multiclass)

    model = Model(inputs, outputs, name="U-Net")
    return model
```

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator,
steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
validation_steps=steps_per_epoch, epochs=5)``

```
the input size is :(80, 80, 3)

odel: "U-Net"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_11 (InputLayer)           [(None, 80, 80, 3)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_161 (Conv2D)             (None, 80, 80, 64)   1792        input_11[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_152 (BatchN (None, 80, 80, 64)   256         conv2d_161[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_152 (Activation)     (None, 80, 80, 64)   0           batch_normalization_152[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_162 (Conv2D)             (None, 80, 80, 64)   36928       activation_152[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_153 (BatchN (None, 80, 80, 64)   256         conv2d_162[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_153 (Activation)     (None, 80, 80, 64)   0           batch_normalization_153[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_40 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 40, 40, 64)   0           activation_153[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_163 (Conv2D)             (None, 40, 40, 128)  73856       max_pooling2d_40[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_154 (BatchN (None, 40, 40, 128)  512         conv2d_163[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_154 (Activation)     (None, 40, 40, 128)  0           batch_normalization_154[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_164 (Conv2D)             (None, 40, 40, 128)  147584      activation_154[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_155 (BatchN (None, 40, 40, 128)  512         conv2d_164[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_155 (Activation)     (None, 40, 40, 128)  0           batch_normalization_155[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_41 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 20, 20, 128)  0           activation_155[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_165 (Conv2D)             (None, 20, 20, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_41[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_156 (BatchN (None, 20, 20, 256)  1024        conv2d_165[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_156 (Activation)     (None, 20, 20, 256)  0           batch_normalization_156[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_166 (Conv2D)             (None, 20, 20, 256)  590080      activation_156[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_157 (BatchN (None, 20, 20, 256)  1024        conv2d_166[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_157 (Activation)     (None, 20, 20, 256)  0           batch_normalization_157[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_42 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 10, 10, 256)  0           activation_157[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_167 (Conv2D)             (None, 10, 10, 512)  1180160     max_pooling2d_42[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_158 (BatchN (None, 10, 10, 512)  2048        conv2d_167[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_158 (Activation)     (None, 10, 10, 512)  0           batch_normalization_158[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_168 (Conv2D)             (None, 10, 10, 512)  2359808     activation_158[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_159 (BatchN (None, 10, 10, 512)  2048        conv2d_168[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_159 (Activation)     (None, 10, 10, 512)  0           batch_normalization_159[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_43 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 5, 5, 512)    0           activation_159[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_169 (Conv2D)             (None, 5, 5, 1024)   4719616     max_pooling2d_43[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_160 (BatchN (None, 5, 5, 1024)   4096        conv2d_169[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_160 (Activation)     (None, 5, 5, 1024)   0           batch_normalization_160[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_170 (Conv2D)             (None, 5, 5, 1024)   9438208     activation_160[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_161 (BatchN (None, 5, 5, 1024)   4096        conv2d_170[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_161 (Activation)     (None, 5, 5, 1024)   0           batch_normalization_161[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_29 (Conv2DTran (None, 10, 10, 512)  2097664     activation_161[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_29 (Concatenate)    (None, 10, 10, 1024) 0           conv2d_transpose_29[0][0]        
                                                                 activation_159[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_171 (Conv2D)             (None, 10, 10, 512)  4719104     concatenate_29[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_162 (BatchN (None, 10, 10, 512)  2048        conv2d_171[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_162 (Activation)     (None, 10, 10, 512)  0           batch_normalization_162[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_172 (Conv2D)             (None, 10, 10, 512)  2359808     activation_162[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_163 (BatchN (None, 10, 10, 512)  2048        conv2d_172[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_163 (Activation)     (None, 10, 10, 512)  0           batch_normalization_163[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_30 (Conv2DTran (None, 20, 20, 256)  524544      activation_163[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_30 (Concatenate)    (None, 20, 20, 512)  0           conv2d_transpose_30[0][0]        
                                                                 activation_157[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_173 (Conv2D)             (None, 20, 20, 256)  1179904     concatenate_30[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_164 (BatchN (None, 20, 20, 256)  1024        conv2d_173[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_164 (Activation)     (None, 20, 20, 256)  0           batch_normalization_164[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_174 (Conv2D)             (None, 20, 20, 256)  590080      activation_164[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_165 (BatchN (None, 20, 20, 256)  1024        conv2d_174[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_165 (Activation)     (None, 20, 20, 256)  0           batch_normalization_165[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_31 (Conv2DTran (None, 40, 40, 128)  131200      activation_165[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_31 (Concatenate)    (None, 40, 40, 256)  0           conv2d_transpose_31[0][0]        
                                                                 activation_155[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_175 (Conv2D)             (None, 40, 40, 128)  295040      concatenate_31[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_166 (BatchN (None, 40, 40, 128)  512         conv2d_175[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_166 (Activation)     (None, 40, 40, 128)  0           batch_normalization_166[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_176 (Conv2D)             (None, 40, 40, 128)  147584      activation_166[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_167 (BatchN (None, 40, 40, 128)  512         conv2d_176[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_167 (Activation)     (None, 40, 40, 128)  0           batch_normalization_167[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_32 (Conv2DTran (None, 80, 80, 64)   32832       activation_167[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_32 (Concatenate)    (None, 80, 80, 128)  0           conv2d_transpose_32[0][0]        
                                                                 activation_153[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_177 (Conv2D)             (None, 80, 80, 64)   73792       concatenate_32[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_168 (BatchN (None, 80, 80, 64)   256         conv2d_177[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_168 (Activation)     (None, 80, 80, 64)   0           batch_normalization_168[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_178 (Conv2D)             (None, 80, 80, 64)   36928       activation_168[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_169 (BatchN (None, 80, 80, 64)   256         conv2d_178[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_169 (Activation)     (None, 80, 80, 64)   0           batch_normalization_169[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_179 (Conv2D)             (None, 80, 80, 1)    65          activation_169[0][0]             
==================================================================================================
Total params: 31,055,297
Trainable params: 31,043,521
Non-trainable params: 11,776
```